# How to show the array values using one matching value and display it as a table

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I need to combine the value of array by a field dg_id and get results of mark and cnt. dg_id field value should be unique. Refer my code below

1.Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01aa 
                [mark] => A 
                [cnt] => 24653 
                ) 
    [1] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01aa 
                [mark] => O 
                [cnt] => 149 
                ) 
    [2] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01aa 
                [mark] => U 
                [cnt] => 198 
                ) 
    [3] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01ab 
                [mark] => A 
                [cnt] => 19259 
                ) 
    [4] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01ab 
                [mark] => O 
                [cnt] => 121 
                ) 
    [5] => Array 
                ( 
                [dg_id] => ht01ab 
                [mark] => U 
                [cnt] => 153 ) 
                ) 
    )
```

2. How to get output like this way

   ```
       +--------+--------+--------+-------+
       | dg_id  |   A    |    O   |   U   |
       +--------+--------+--------+-------+
       | ht01aa |  24653 |    149 |   198 |
       | ht01ab |  19259 |    121 |   153 |
   ```

3.I have tried the code

```
        $temp = '';
        echo '<table cellpadding="10px">';
        foreach ($status_array as $key1 => $val1) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($val1 as $key2 => $val2) {
                if ($key2 == $status_array['dg_id'] && $temp!= $val2) {
                    $temp = $val2;
                    echo "<td><b>" . $val2 . "</b></td>";
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                else if ($key2 == 'cnt']){
                    echo "<td>" . $val2 . "</td>";
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

4.My current output

```
        dg_Id   A       O     U     
        ht01aa  24653 
        149 
        198 
        ht01ab  19259 
        121 
        153
```

5. query

   ```
    $status="select concat(dg,fg,block) as dg_id, mark, count(*) as cnt from ".$table." group by 1,2 limit 15";
    $status_fetch=mysql_query($status,$link1);
    $status_array = array(); 
       while ($row_status = mysql_fetch_array($status_fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC))
           {
            $status_array[] = $row_status;
           }
   ```

but didn't get a proper solution. Anyone help me to solve this..

Comment: Start by fixing your query. Make it use alias for the column names and then the array will make more sense. Like `SELECT concat(dg,fg,block) as dg_id, mark, count(*) as cnt FROM .....`

Comment: you have two ways to solve this problem : 1) from your sql query 2) make new array from old array contains your data as you like

Comment: @puvi do you have the query??

Comment: You might like to look into whats called [Pivot Table](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) in MySQL

Comment: Ya i update my query nw @mohade refer my question

Comment: i'm looking to it @RiggsFolly

Comment: @puvi try this query $status="select concat(dg,fg,block) as dg_id,if(mark=A,count(*),0) as A,if(mark=O,count(*),0) as O,if(mark=U,count(*),0) as U from ".$table." GROUP BY dg_id";

Comment: it doesn't work @mohade

Comment: It is difficult to understand pivot table @RiggsFolly

Comment: wait a minute and i give you the query

Comment: @puvi try now $status="select concat(dg,fg,block) as dg_id,sum(if(mark='A',count(*),0)) as A,sum(if(mark='O',count(*),0)) as O,sum(if(mark='U',count(*),0)) as U from ".$table." GROUP BY dg_id";

Comment: it doesn't work either @mohade

Comment: The site delete * from query I don't know why ..try to edit the query and add stars in count

Comment: And give me the error

Comment: mysql> select concat(dg,fg,block) as dg_id,sum(if(mark='A',count(*),0)) as A,sum(if(mark='O',count(*),0)) as O,sum(if(mark='U',count(*),0)) as U from dt_ht_aol GROUP BY dg_id  
   -> ;
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
@mohade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the array value from query then start with the for each loop

```
 $result_array= Array();
            foreach( $status_array as $fa )
            {
                $result_array[$fa["dg_id"]][($fa["mark"])] += $fa["cnt"];
            }
```

To produce the following

```
Array (  
       [ht01aa] => Array ( 
                          [A] => 24203 
                          [O] => 323 
                          [U] => 474 
                      ) 
       [ht01ab] => Array ( 
                         [A] => 18639 
                         [O] => 392 
                         [U] => 502 
                      ) 
      )
```

Then by using another for each loop assign the array value to a table

```
  foreach ($result_array as $dg_id => $result) 
      {
                $keyA = "A";
                $keyO = "O";
                $keyU = "U";

                echo "<tr>
                          <td>{$dg_id}</td>            
                          <td>{$result[$keyA]}</td>
                          <td>{$result[$keyO]}</td>
                          <td>{$result[$keyU]}</td>
                      </tr>

      }
```

this works for me :)